# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I'm getting this error in my Hibernate desktop application:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

It's not creating `SessionFactory` and giving this exception:

```
Executing E:\Vishal\summer\EmpMan\dist\run1432002073\EmpMan.jar using platform C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre/bin/java
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:~/EmpMan]
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jul 04, 2017 2:24:35 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

That's it. I'm getting only this much information.

My **hibernate.cfg.xml** file configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/EmpMan</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password">sa</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="models.AdminDetails"/>
        <mapping class="models.EmployeeDetails" />
        <mapping class="models.DepartmentDetails" />
        <mapping class="models.DailyDataDetails"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Notice:

=> I'm using h2 database and I want to configure embedded database

=> I'm using netbeans and Java8 with hibernate version 5.2.10

=> I'm new to h2 database

=> Where to locate my EmpMan database in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved : I have already exist same named database so i changed name and now it's working :) Thank you guys